# How to set the consumer-tag value in spring-amqp

Tags: java, amqp, spring-amqp

I am trying to update the consumer-tag to be more informative than the randomly generated string. We have a pattern which we use that includes hostname + identifier + randomized string. This works fine in our other services (ie: NodeJS with `ampqlib`) because they provide a mechanism to pass in this value.

However, for our Java services, we use `spring-amqp` and it looks like there is no way to pass in a consumer-tag value. I took a look at `BlockingQueueConsumer` and it is currently hard-coded to an empty string:

```
String consumerTag = this.channel.basicConsume(queue, this.acknowledgeMode.isAutoAck(), "", false, this.exclusive,
            this.consumerArgs, this.consumer);
```

Is there any way to get it not to be an empty string (which will result in a randomly generated one) besides creating our own type of consumer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct; it's not currently configurable; please open an [Improvement JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll take a look at adding it. It shouldn't take much effort.

**EDIT**

If using `@RabbitListener`, simply add the strategy implementation to the listener container factory; it's a `@FunctionalInterface` so you can use a lambda, for example, with Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConsumerTagStrategy(q -> "myConsumerFor." + q);
    return factory;
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
public void listen(String in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

and

[image: ScreenShot]

If wiring up the container directly, simply add it to the container.

[Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#consumerTags).

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else is interested, here is the ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-493

Comment: With the ticket closed, could you please complete your answer with a small example?

Comment: What if you have multiple consumers and you want unique tags for each, let's say "consumer.foo.1, consumer.foo.2..."(not the default ones)?

Comment: `q -> "myConsumerFor." + q + "." + counter.incrementAndGet())` where `counter` is an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Check my alternative which is consider better in the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119596/how-to-set-amqp-rabbitmq-consumer-tag-in-spring-boot/75784413#75784413)

Answer (score 1):

It works for the basic amqp java library as well (for those without spring-amqp). When calling the basicConsume method, it can receive a String parameter that will represent the consumer tag to be used. If it's empty or null, it will use a server generated one. You should be careful to use server-wide unique tags, as cancelling a consumer with a duplicate tag might have unwanted behavior.

```java
channel.basicConsume(queueName, autoAck, "specific.tag."+System.currentTimeMillis(), deliverCallback);
```