# How to set amqp RabbitMQ consumer tag in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

In question [How to set the consumer-tag value in spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29801873/3127111) it is being asked how to change the consumer tag when using Spring Amqp and the answer suggests to provide an implementation of `ConsumerTagStrategy`.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.5 and I'm trying to figure out if I can do the same customization, though I can't find any configuration property about that nor providing a bean of type `ConsumerTagStrategy` seems to work.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override boot's container factory bean declaration and add it there.

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConsumerTagStrategy(q -> "myConsumerFor." + q);
    return factory;
}
```

[image: Tag]

Answer (score 0):

Even Gary's answer is very good it is not working always. For example in Spring Boot with autoconfiguration and using `RabbitListener` you probably end with some weird situation where application refuse to start or your factory will not be used. I would recommend to used `BeanPostProcessor` instead. There is a simple example following:

```java
@Component
public class ConsumerTagByAppSetter implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final String appName;

    public ConsumerTagByAppSetter(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(@NonNull Object bean, @NonNull String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory) {
            ((SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory) bean).setConsumerTagStrategy(q -> appName + "." + q);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This post processor is applied to the factory created and customized by auto configuration and changes just the way how consumer tag is generated which I consider much safer and out of the box than trying to start from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to override SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.

It is enough to customize it by creating the extra bean which will be applied by spring boot autoconfiguration.

```
    @Bean
    ContainerCustomizer<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> containerCustomizer(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String applicationName) {
        return container -> container.setConsumerTagStrategy(queue -> applicationName + "_" + UUID.randomUUID());
    }
```